# Android Studio not recognizing any of my textviews

Tags: java, android, textview

When I search for the views by their id's, i find them. But when I use the variables that store the textviews, they can't be recognized and i'm constantly told that they are no where to be found. My button don't give me probles. Only the textviews keeps saying "Cannot resolve symbol"

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button1, button2, button3;
    button1 = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1));
    button2 = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button2));
    button3 = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button3));
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    TextView textview1, textview2, textview3, questionView, questionView2, questionNumber;

    textview1 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1));
    textview2 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2));
    textview3 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3));
    questionView = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionView));
    questionView2 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionView2));
    questionNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionNumber);
}

   @Override

        public void onClick( View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:



                    if(questionIndex < questions.length -1
                            )

                        if (questionIndex != 5){
                            textview2.setText("");
                        } if (questionIndex == 5){
                    textview2.setText(halfQues8);
                }

                    // make sure the index is in bounds

                    questionIndex++ ; // increment the index


                    questionValue ++;



                    questionView.setText(Questions[questionIndex]); // set the text to the next question

    /*
     * set the text to the next answer options
     */
                    textview1.setText(answerButtA[questionIndex]);
                    textview2.setText(answerButtB[questionIndex]);
                    textview3.setText(answerButtC[questionIndex]);
                    questionNumber.setText("Question " + questionValueS + ".");

            }

            else{

                questionView.setText("Complete");
                questionNumber.setText("");
                questionView2.setText("");

                textview1.setText("");
                textview2.setText("");
                textview3.setText("");
                Results.setText("Click here for results");
            }






            break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    //DO something
                    break;
                case R.id.button3:
                    //DO something
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: Is it only an IDE issue ? Can you compile and run your project ?

Comment: That's because they're declared in your method and not in your class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared your buttons as method/local variables. Therefore you can't access them from another method. In order to solve this declare them as global variables
Eg:

```
Button button1, button2, button3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button1 = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your TextViews are local variables.
Assign them to member fields so that they are visible in your onClick overload.